# Why is there a red bar in the dope sheet?

Tags: dopesheet

There's a red bar in my dope sheet that I noticed as indicated by the red arrows. Is that a bad thing or is that just part of blender?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's the Summary channel highlight:

[image: highlight]

Only the Dopesheet shows it because only that editor shows channels highlights outside the channel list.